# Why does the I2C debugger send NOT ACK?

Tags: pic, i2c, embedded

I am simulating a master-slave scenario.
The master is the PIC18F4620, the slave is the I2C debugger.

I am sending a slave address of 0x04.
R/W = 0 to perform a write operation on the slave.

This is my frame format.

```
        //Slave address is 0x04.
        mcal_i2c_send_slave_address(0x04,0,&ack_status);
        //Send data = 0x77
        mcal_i2c_master_send_data(0x77,&ack_status);
        //send repeated start
        mcal_i2c_send_repeated_start_condition();
        //send data = 0x00 , then send stop condition.
        mcal_i2c_master_send_data(0x00,&ack_status);
        mcal_i2c_send_stop_condition();
```

The transmitter which is the PIC18F is transmitting the frame correctly.
The problem is that the I2C debugger won`t send ACK, it only sends NOT ACK.

Does anybody know why I am receiving NACK from the I2C debugger?

[image]

Comment: A debugger is not intended to be an active participant on the bus, it is only there to monitor the interaction between the controller and the appication device(s).

Comment: I see video tutorials on youtube that the debugger responds with ACK

Comment: Maybe some debuggers can be put into a "device emulation" mode. Relatively straightforward to do for generic devices like memories; it'd be much more difficult to do the broader range of I2C sensors and other devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugger just monitors bus activity and logs it. It doesn't transmit anything on the bus itself, it just records what other devices transmit.

So the debugger's not transmitting a NACK or transmitting anything. A NACK is just SDA left pulled high during that bit period and detecting no bus activity looks the same as detecting a NACK.

Answer (score 0):

The waveform sends start and 0x00, so if that is not a valid device address then no device sends ACK.

Note that there is no ACK for the byte 0x77 either.

Comment: The waveform shown is just a screenshot.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. Screenshot or not, the I2C protocol is still wrong. There is no address sent after start.

Comment: In the code snippet i sent 0x04 as the slave address, it is sent but i didn't take a screenshot of it on the waveform

Comment: It is although shown on the i2c debugger widnow

Comment: @MuhammedElmaghraby The "Sr 00" confirms it's wrong. Anyway, that's a separate problem, if you don't have anything on bus that would ACK an address.